# What is the meaning of the phrase 'gone are the days' and how is it used?

Tags: phrase-usage

Kindly tell me about the usage of following phrases 
1) Gone are the days
2) Gone were the days
3) Gone are those days
4) Gone were those days

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Kindly tell me the General usage of aforesaid phrases.

Comment: That's not specific, Saleem. As it stands, you're asking about the difference between _are_ and _were_, and between _the_ and _those_. You can look both those words up in any dictionary or grammar book for explanations, which makes the question off-topic.

Comment: I am asking neither the differences of *are and were* nor the *the and those*. I am asking about the contextual usage of aforementioned phrases, for instance when citing some event or phenomena, which one sound well to use.

Comment: @Saleem Ul Haq: As you don't seem to be a native speaker, it would probably be best to simply avoid this usage completely. It's a quaint dated/frozen form with unmistakeably non-standard word order that you wouldn't often encounter in natural *speech* today. Even in writing there's a good chance you'll use it in an inappropriately - why take the risk for an outdated usage?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - `+1` - Using phrases like *gone are the days* takes deep cultural familiarity to pull off at all naturally.

Comment: @Carl: Perzactly! I'd guess the vast majority of *contemporary* spoken instances would be to a greater or lesser extent "facetious" (or at least somewhat "self-conscious"). And if you see it in written form *without* any such connotations, it's usually just a trite cliche reflecting nostalgia both in form and semantic content. As you say, tricky to get "right" without both general cultural background *and* a clear grasp of the specific context in terms of register, target audience, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I only really use 1). It's idiomatic and used when wistfully describing something in the past.

> Gone are the days when children would play outside.
>   Gone are the days when I could play football without worrying about my knee.

2, 3 and 4 sound odd to me, I wouldn't use them, but they are grammatical.

Comment: There's nothing unidiomatic about 2, 3, and 4; they just require slightly different (and less commonly occurring) contexts.

Comment: The OP is concerned with the *usage*, which, for those three variants, is negligible.